# High dimensional sampling with low measurement noise

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, high-dimensional

Assume that you have a model

$$ Y = G(\Theta) + \varepsilon,$$

where $\Theta$ is a parameter vector with $\sim 8$ dimensions, $G$ is a highly nonlinear function of the parameters, $Y$ is observed measurements and $\varepsilon$ is a multivariate normal measurement noise with low variance (which is known). You are interested in the posterior
$$ p(\Theta | Y), $$
which can potentially be multimodal. What type of algorithm would you use? I have thought about using MCMC, but I run into numerical problems since most proposed $\Theta^*$ will essentially give densities $p(G(\Theta^*) | Y)$ which are $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I recommend that your underlying inference algorithm works with the log-transformed likelihood. If your likelihood is close to zero, this will improve numerical stability.

Second, besides using MCMC, you might be interested in BUS (Straub, Daniel, and Iason Papaioannou. "Bayesian updating with structural reliability methods." Journal of Engineering Mechanics (2014). http://www.era.bgu.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bkd/www/Papers/2014_Manuscript_Bayesian_Updating_final.pdf) - I am talking in particular about using Subset Simulation (Au, Siu-Kui, and James L. Beck. "Estimation of small failure probabilities in high dimensions by subset simulation." Probabilistic Engineering Mechanics 16.4 (2001): 263-277.) for Bayesian updating: (Betz, Wolfgang, Iason Papaioannou, and Daniel Straub. "Adaptive variant of the BUS approach to Bayesian updating." Eurodyn 2014 (2014). http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1210607/1210607.pdf)

**Advantages:**

- can handle multimodal posteriors efficiently
- generates *perfect* samples from the posterior - no *burn-in* required
- dimensionality is not an issue, because the underlying MCMC sampling is done e.g. component-wise

**Disadvantages:**

- The implementation is advanced - and it is difficult to do it the right way.

If you are looking for a more established alternative, go for TMCMC (Ching, Jianye, and Yi-Chu Chen. "Transitional Markov chain Monte Carlo method for Bayesian model updating, model class selection, and model averaging." Journal of engineering mechanics 133.7 (2007): 816-832.).